# changing uploaded file in JSP through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

Can any one give me proper example for changing uploaded file in JSP?

This is my JSP Page code.

```
<div class="action">
<input type="file" name="files[0]" id="file0" style="float: left" required> 
<input type="button" id="btnZoomIn" value="+" style="float: left">
<input type="button" id="btnZoomOut" value="-" style="float: left">
<input type="button" id="btnCrop" value="Crop" style="float: left">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" style="float: right" />
</div>


<div class="cropped">
</div>
```

Using JS and CSS i am cropping uploaded image ...

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('#btnCrop').addEventListener('click',
                            function() {
                                var img = cropper.getDataURL();

                                document.querySelector('.cropped').innerHTML = '<img name="img123" src="'+img+'">';


                            })
```

this

```
 cropper.getDataURL()
```

will provide me cropped image but now i am unable to set this image to uploaded file like as a file0 or files[0] to pass it to my servlet. How can i do so?

Comment: Try to reproduce your issue use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9umfvh9/)

Comment: I am not familiar with this.

Comment: If you have any proper example for cropping and uploading image in jsp and sending it to servlet,share it